# Creating an array from a text file and organizing it in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a program that can read a text file and place all the words in the file into an array, it can then organize the array alphabetically, remove all the symbols that are not letters, and make all the letters lowercase.

So far, I've only been able to read the text file and then spit out all the data in a column.  When I try to move the printing portion into it's own function, it breaks.

I'm also trying to make it possible to insert a word into an array but I haven't been too successful with that either.

Here's the code I've gotten so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
FILE *fp;
FILE *fp2;
int wordcount = 1;
int i,x;
char filename[100];
Start: printf("Insert Filename: \n");
gets(&filename);
fp = fopen(filename, "rw+");
char ch;
if (fp == NULL){
    printf("Error, file is NULL.\n");
    goto Start; //Reprompts you
    }
else
    while (ch != EOF) 
    {
        if (ch==' '||ch=='\n')
            {
                wordcount += 1;
            }
                ch = fgetc(fp);
    }
char *Table[wordcount]; 
fp2 = fopen(filename, "r"); //For some reason I had to reopen the file for the next two to work.
for (i = 0; i < wordcount; ++i) {
    Table[i] = malloc(128); 
    fscanf(fp2, "%127s", Table[i]);
}
for (i = 0; i < wordcount; ++i){ //This is what prints the array
    printf("%d: %s\n", i, Table[i]);}
 /*Functions I'm trying to add*/
     void print(char *Table[], int wordcount){
     }
     int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int wordcount){
     }
fclose(fp2);
fclose(fp);
 }
```

So how should I proceed from here? I'm extremely lost and if this was python I'd be done by now but C is very confusing for me.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: A few things.  Don't use goto.  The reason you had to re-open the file is because you were already at the end of it because you read the whole thing to get the word count.  What exactly breaks?  Is this a class project or something you're doing on your own?  C++ is a little more user friendly coming from python (but not by much).

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem, but `fgetc` returns `int`, so it should be `int ch;` even then `ch` was not initialised before first use.

Comment: @ChaseHenslee Class project, otherwise I'd be using python for this since C isn't the best for file processing from what I'm learning over the past 2 days of trying to figure this out.

Comment: On my previous pedantic point, `while (ch != EOF)` is testing an uninitialised variable. This should be `while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` and delete the `fgetc` line in the body of that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up partial version that does objective 1, along with some cleanup [that has been suggested in comments]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Functions I'm trying to add */
void
print(char **Table,int wordcount)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < wordcount; ++i) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, Table[i]);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    //FILE *fp2;
    int wordcount = 0;
    int i;
    char *cp;
    //int x;
    char ch;
    char filename[100];

    while (1) {
        printf("Insert Filename: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        cp = fgets(filename,sizeof(filename),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            continue;

        cp = strchr(filename,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fp != NULL)
            break;

        printf("Error, file is NULL.\n");
    }

    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        switch (ch) {
        case ' ':
        case '\n':
            wordcount += 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // For some reason I had to reopen the file for the next two to work.
#if 0
    fp2 = fopen(filename, "r");
#else
    rewind(fp);
#endif

    char *Table[wordcount];

    for (i = 0; i < wordcount; ++i) {
        Table[i] = malloc(128);
        fscanf(fp, "%127s", Table[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // This is what prints the array
#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < wordcount; ++i) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, Table[i]);
    }
#else
    print(Table,wordcount);
#endif

#if 0
    int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int wordcount) {
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

What is your exact definition of "insert"?  I would have coded that.

Comment: All I'm looking for it to do currently is insert into the array, from there I'd try and find a way to arrange the array properly alphabetically.  Thanks a lot for the code by the way!

Comment: @CraigEstey comments also suggested you correctly use `int ch`

Comment: @CraigEstey Your code has memory leeks.   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 1 frees, 2,088 bytes allocated
==4100== 1,536 bytes in 12 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1 and like WeatherVane sad, you should use int ch not char ch.

Comment: @Michi I was short on time, but I wasn't trying for a complete rewrite.  Just cleaning up the most egregious stuff.  I missed the int ch, but, because the problem stated _text_ file, the code works fine even with char. There _aren't_ any memory "leeks" [sp. leaks]--your numbers are nonsense without an input file. The insert function hasn't yet been written.  And, the free loop could be added at the end--but if you're just terminating afterwards, the free loop is just wasted CPU time.  I was balancing rewrite vs the code still being recognizable [therefore instructive].

Comment: @ICantCode4Shit You're welcome.  I recently had to learn python [self taught].  From zero to first pgm was two hours.  Then I started hitting things as I started using more constructs [spent much search on (e.g. "python list append")], so I felt empathetic.  I also threw you a deliberate curve ball with the "switch", since I [now] know that python doesn't have one.  I've been doing C for 30+ and perl5 for 20+, so I was surprised by python's list intrinsic.  perl's list intrinsic is like python's deque class.  Future challenge for you:  do full deque impl. in C ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fseek() to re-read the file instead of using a second fopen(). If there's enough room to store all the words as 128 byte strings, there's probably enough room to read the entire file into memory. You could use fseek(), ftell(), to get file size, fseek() or rewind() to "rewind" the file, allocate that much memory, then read the entire file into memory. You could then scan the file image once to get a word count, then scan again to set the array of pointers to point to the start of each word. I suggest you replace the ending spaces or newlines with zero to make the words strings.

```
char *pdata;
FILE *fp;
long filesize;
    /* read entire file into memory */
    fp=fopen(..., "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    pdata = malloc(filesize);
    fread(pdata, 1, filesize, fp);
    // scan to get word count and set word terminators to zero
    // scan for words setting pointers in Table[];
    // ...
    free(pdata);   // free memory when done
```